# Web Essentials SASS Line numbers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I am having an issue with Web Essentials 2013 for SASS compilation. When I compile my SASS files the output CSS is littered with comments like:

```
/* SURVEY header, body, footer */
/* line 2, [filelocationhere] */
```

I understand that libsass does this when the option `line_numbers` is set to true, but I cannot figure out how to set it to false in Web Essentials. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: does the option for "output style" in the Tools > Options > web Essentials > SASS help?

Comment: Well, my entire team is using a shared WebEssentials-Settings.json file and I'm the only person outputting comments. It's upsetting my team, and none of us could figure out whats causing the issue. :/ OutputStyle is set to "Expanded".

Comment: what does it matter? are you just worried about the css file getting checked out every time you build? You shouldn't really be looking at the css file much if you're building it with SASS

Comment: Not all of us have WebEssentials installed due to various circumstances, so we actually need to check out the .css files so others on our team can use the new css... They are concerned about the readability of the files considering there are more comments than actual css.

Comment: if you check out the css file, any changes to it will be lost whenever someone rebuilds it from the sass file, like all generated code. You should probably all work off of the css file if some people cannot work with the sass file.

Comment: Only people with WebEssentials are building the CSS, but people who work on the markup templates need to be able to read our CSS...